# problem with removing animation and show full size image HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I write a mini project at html,css,js.
I have an 20% width image that moves with an infinite animation left to right.
for example:

```
.img {
    width: 20%,
    animation: move infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
    from {
        left: 100%;
    }
    to {
        left: -50%;
    }
}
```

I want, when I press the image to come to the center of the screen with its actual width.
My problem is when I remove the animation class (cause it needs to stop moving), I lose the left & top attributes of the image and also the transition from 20% width to full-width does not work smoothly. Any ideas on how this can be implemented?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You basically wrote the requirements correctly in the question. The problem is, you did not code step by step what you want. Read again your requirements like so:

> **1.** I have an 20% width image that moves with an infinite animation left to right
>
> **2.** I want, when I press the image to come to the center of the screen with its actual width.
>
> **3.** My problem is when I remove the animation class (cause it needs to stop moving)

So basically there are 3 states:

1. `the image` with what ever styles, image class => `.img`
2. `animation` the image has some sort of animation, animation class => `.animate`
3. `finished` at some stage we have a "finished" animation state, finished class => `.finish`

Like so you have defined three states in CSS where you can later just add/remove properties for any given state and you can add/remove the classes to the element (in this case the image).

(Cause it is really hard to click on a moving element, I've created a wrapper with a click-area. Obviously you can change the click event listener back to the image and try, it's really hard to click it...)

```js
var image = document.querySelector('img');
var clickArea = document.querySelector('.click-area');
clickArea.addEventListener('click', function(){
    image.classList.add('finish');
    image.classList.remove('animate');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 2px orange;
}

.img {
    position: absolute;
}

.finish {
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Opera */
}

.animate {
    width: 20%;
    animation: move infinite 2s;
}

@keyframes move {
    from { left: 100%; }
    to { left: -50%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper click-area">
  <img class="img animate" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
```

**If there are multiple of those images on the same page it's almost the same!** Figure out the differences for yourself.

```js
var clickAreas = document.querySelectorAll('.click-area');

[...clickAreas].forEach(function(clickArea){
    var image = clickArea.querySelector('img'); // find only the image inside the click-area
    clickArea.addEventListener('click', function(){
        image.classList.add('finish');
        image.classList.remove('animate');
    });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; /* tweaked the height so we can see more the just one */
  border: solid 2px orange;
}

.img {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;  /* tweaked the height so we can see more the just one */
    height: 100px;  /* tweaked the height so we can see more the just one */
}

.finish {
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Opera */
}

.animate {
    width: 20%;
    animation: move infinite 2s;
}

@keyframes move {
    from { left: 100%; }
    to { left: -50%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper click-area">
  <img class="img animate" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper click-area">
  <img class="img animate" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper click-area">
  <img class="img animate" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
```